# Langchain zapier NLA actions integration issues

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, zapier

Currently using langchain 0.1.9, I am not able to integrate with zapier. With the API key I am able to list the zapier NLA actions but not able to interact with any of the actions.

Like I am not able to find email from my account. The LLM is hallucinating and I am not able to see any error message. Moreover I am not seeing any logs of connection to that particular action. I was able to do it with older langchain versions but not working with latest versions. Please let me know how can this be fixed

I tried connecting with zapier API key from langchain. It is connecting and getting me the nla actions list but not able to interact with actions

Thanks,

Shah